# How to conditionally define a new command in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX code with an older version of some package. Thus, I'm having a few issues due to undefined commands.

How can I add conditional code so that I can define some work-around commands of this older package version?

```
% I want something like this:
if command \foobar is not defined
  \newcommand{\foobar}{FooBar}

% I don't need an "else" clause here, but it would be good
% to know how to add one, in case I need it in future

end if
```

Comment: Doesn't `\newcommand` contains a built-in check that the command you are trying to define is not already defined?

Comment: @Willie Wong: But then it complains horribly that it's already defined.  I guess the point here is to silently fail if the command is already defined.

Comment: Ah, it seems I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel command `\providecommand{\foobar}{FooBar}` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 53):

I think that `\providecommand` is what you want for this, as lockstep says, but it's worth mentioning the `\@ifundefined` LaTeX command which tests for whether or not a command is defined and executes some code if it is or isn't.  It's more flexible than `\providecommand` in that it doesn't just deal with defining a particular command.  Here's a simple example that I use when anglicising a few commands:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{centre}{%
\newenvironment{centre}{\center}{\endcenter}%
}{}
\makeatother
```

So if the *command* `\centre` is not defined then it defines the *environment* `centre`.

Comment: This should be promoted. This is a nice way to define environments as well as commands conditionally which I was about to ask about separately.

Answer (score 25):

The [ifthen package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/ifthen.html) provides some easy-to-use macros for this.  For example:

```
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\foobar}}{
  %% Do this if it is undefined
}{
  %% Do this if it is defined
}
```

You can also do it in plain TeX (which doesn't require any external packages):

```
\ifx\foobar\undefined
  %% Do this if it is undefined
\else
  %% Do this if it is defined
\fi
```

Comment: How do you define `foobar`? Like, `\def\foobar` would work?

Answer (score 17):

The e-TeX primitives that LaTeX wraps (apparently) are `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname`. Use like this:

```
\ifdefined \foobar \else
  \newcommand{\foobar}{FooBar}
\fi
```

Use `\ifcsname` if you need to construct the command name with macros:

```
\ifcsname foobar\endcsname \else
  \newcommand{\foobar}{FooBar}
\fi
```

The `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname` control sequences do not exist in the original tex program, but they do in all latex/xetex/pdftex variants on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: These commands are no TeX primitives, but defined in e-tex. In newer tex distributions, latex usually links to pdftex, which includes the e-tex extensions already. If you run your code snippets through plain tex you'll see, that they won't work, running them through etex works. Good answer nonetheless.

Comment: There seems to be conflicting statements here. The first sentence says `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname` are TeX primitives, and the last sentence says otherwise.