# How to test whether the starred-version of a command is defined?

Tags: macros, conditionals, starred-version

This question is similar to [How to conditionally define a new command in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/how-to-conditionally-define-a-new-command-in-latex) but I want to test if the starred version of a command is defined.

The naive thing

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ref*}{}{}
\makeatother
```

doesn't work, for example, for testing whether a starred version of `\ref` is defined (say, by `hyperref`) as it always returns true.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, there is no starred version of a command.  What really happens is that the unstarred command checks to see if there is a star as the first argument and passes control to different auxiliary macros accordingly, or simply executes two different sets of commands.

So, to take a random example, we look at `\endlargethispage` and find that it is defined as:

```
\gdef \enlargethispage {%
   \@ifstar
     {%
      \@enlargepage{\hbox{\kern\p@}}}%
     {%
      \@enlargepage\@empty}%
}
```

The `\@ifstar` is the key here which tests for a wandering star.

It's clear from this example that there is no easy test for whether `\enlargethispage*` is valid.  The most exact test that I can think of is to examine `\meaning\enlargethispage` for the presence of `\@ifstar`, but even that won't catch everything (`\let\my@ifstar=\@ifstar`) and might also produce a false positive (since `\meaning` converts to a token list of characters and so looking for an exact token inside it might be fooled).  But that would be complicated to implement and maybe there is an easier way to achieve whatever it is that you want to achieve.

Comment: Both very good answers, accepting this one sort of randomly, and because the last sentence got me thinking enough to come up with another way around my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This is not basically possible, and I'll try to explain why, on an example.

Let's `\show\section`:

```
\section=\long macro:
-> \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus
   -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }
```

Ok, not much to see, other than that *`\section` takes no arguments at all!* So let's `\show\@startsection`:

```
\@startsection=macro:
#1#2#3#4#5#6->\if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi \par \@tempskipa #4\relax \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@ \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse \fi
  \if@nobreak \everypar {}\else \addpenalty \@secpenalty \addvspace \@tempskipa \fi
  \@ifstar {\@ssect {#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}{\@dblarg {\@sect {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}
```

Voilà! It is the `\@ifstar` in the definition of `\@startsection` that tells you that `\section` has a starred variant. How does it work? Notice that `\section` passes to `\@startsection` all the 6 mandatory arguments, therefore if you write `\section*{BLA}`, it becomes `\@startsection{<6 arguments>}*{BLA}` and this becomes `blablabla \@ifstar {\@ssect {#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}{\@dblarg {\@sect {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}*{BLA}`. Finally, `\@ifstar` is a crazily-made command that has two arguments, 1st is used if `*` follows and 2nd if not.

So, as you can see, checking whether a starred variant of a command is defined, is really not simple. Not to mention that `\@ifstar` is not the only way how to define a starred variant of a command. The problem is that the star is *not a part of the name of the command*, it is *a first optional argument*.