# \renewcommand or \renewenvironment with multicols

Tags: environments, multicol

I'm trying to create a horizontal white space in my `multicolumn` environment every time I start a new subsection.

It stops people from having to trawl their eyes up and down the page between different content, splitting the page in a more readable fashion.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
        ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
       <to be read again>
       \let
       l.83 \renewenvironment{\subsection}
       {\end{multicols}}{\start{multicols}{2}}
       The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
       not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}


%\let\origsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\end{multicols}\subsection\start{multicols}{2}}

\begin{document}

\section{Something here}
Filler text1

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection{This is a test1}  %\endMulti startsub  \beginMulti
Filler text2
\subsection{This is a test2}  %\endMulti startsub  \beginMulti
Filler text3

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`.

Comment: btw: you're creating an environment but using a macro. Is this intentional?!

Comment: @masu Okay, done sorry. And also yes, though I take it this is bad... I did try using \renewenvironment but the errors were the same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is an [XY problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean) for me right now.

Comment: ah never mind, I'll just do \end{multicols}\subsection{blah}\start{multicols}{2} manually for now. It's only really needed a few times anyhow.

Comment: You get the problem because `\subsection` only opens a `multicols` environment, but doesn't end it. At the end of your last subsection, you should add `\end{multicols}`.

Comment: @KevinC - Modified my question example, but still same result. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had defined `\subsection` in terms of itself which would have been an infinite loop, but you also used a command `\start` that is undefined. You intended something more like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}


\let\origsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\end{multicols}\origsubsection{#1}\begin{multicols}{2}}

\begin{document}

\section{Something here}
Filler text1

\begin{multicols}{2}

\subsection{This is a test1}  %\endMulti startsub  \beginMulti
Filler text2
\subsection{This is a test2}  %\endMulti startsub  \beginMulti
Filler text3

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! I think I did try doing something like this but I must have missed something. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Idea is the same as in the other answer, however, the support for the starred varian and the optional argument was added:

```
\makeatletter
\let\subsection@old\subsection
\def\subsection@pre{\end{multicols}}
\def\subsection@post{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@ifnextchar*\subsection@star\subsection@nostar}
\def\subsection@star*#1{\subsection@pre\old@subsection*{#1}\subsection@post}
\def\subsection@nostar{\@ifnextchar[\subsection@br\subsection@nobr}
\def\subsection@br[#1]#2{\subsection@pre\old@subsection[#1]{#2}\subsection@post}
\def\subsection@nobr#1{\subsection@pre\old@subsection{#1}\subsection@post}
\makeatother
```

Sorry for the (a bit) cryptic code, I don't like using [`\@dblarg`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56329) and [`\@ifstar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148138)

Comment: (+1) essential to mention the starred variant (and the optional argument)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Is this what you wanted?! I hope so. If you also want to change the spacing before `section` and `subsection` check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108747/36821).

I assumed that you have an article (and don't have any chapters). I also assumed that you want the entire stuff to be `twocolumn`, and stop it at every `section` and `subsection` command.

Instead of the `\begin{multicols}` and `\end{multicols}` notation I used the macro calls `\multicols` and `\endmulticols`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % demo only

\usepackage{multicol}

\AtBeginDocument{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}

\makeatletter
\let\section@orig\section
\let\subsection@orig\subsection
\renewcommand\section[1]{\endmulticols\section@orig{#1}\multicols{2}}
\renewcommand\subsection[1]{\endmulticols\subsection@orig{#1}\multicols{2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\show\section
\show\subsection

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Section}

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[5]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Note: `lipsum` is only present for the demo text.

I've also tried to use `xpatch`, but instead of a solution I've created a problem... here's a partial code. I don't know how to fix the issue... `\protect` doesn't seem to solve anything other than removing the errors... Related topic: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % demo only

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\AtBeginDocument{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{multicols}}

\xpretocmd{\section}{\endmulticols}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\section}{\protect\multicols{2}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\subsection}{\endmulticols}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\subsection}{\protect\multicols{2}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[3]

\section{Section}

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[5]

\subsection{Subsection}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you've loaded xpatch but not used it,  but redefined in the classic `\let\subsection@orig\subsection` manner instead (using xpatch might have been an interesting alternative to the other annwers) `\protect` isn't likely to be needed there (you are not likely to use `\subsection` in a moving argument.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've tried that, that's why `xpatch` remained in the code... but `\xapptocmd` didn't seem to work easily (without messing with the internals of the `\section` definition). It messed the titles, and need more tweeking around than this. So this seemed to be more appropriate.

Comment: This is very nice though, exactly what I wanted. @masu - Could you expand a bit on how protect works?

Comment: @tetris11 I've added a reference instead

Comment: as David mentioned, you don't really need the protect there...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added the `xpatch` alternative I've created (but didn't work). Can you suggest anything?