# Reuse of \newsavebox and avoiding compilation warnings

Tags: boxes

The answer here may be obvious but I can't find it. I use `\newsavebox` in many routines and for different purposes. These are saved globally and I guess are a reasonably precious resource.

In all instances the box is used for a variety of purposes immediately after content is saved in the box. I don't care about overwriting previous box content (which can be large).

I decided, to save resources to use the same box for many different things

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
```

I don't know in advance which particular routines I am going to need for a particular document, and I don't want to declare a common box outside of the source for each box use. Consequently there are several declarations of `\newsavebox{\mybox}` (or none at all depending what I am doing).

Bottom line, how can I test for the existence of `\mybox` before re-creating it? MWE is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "and I don't want to declare a common box outside of the source for each box use." why not? that is exactly the intended use. It is normally a mistake to have the `\newxxx` command in a command that is used more than once. plain tex goes to the extreme of declaring `\newbox` to be `\outer` so that using in in another definition is an error.

Comment: I agree with that. I think you misunderstood what I meant - I have several sets of code that do different things (generally just imported into my preamble) - each of those uses a box and declares it - and oftentimes it is the same box (not declaring new boxes within commands at all).

Comment: Ah OK, in that case really you could just allocate a different box to each set there are 32000 of them available these days with etex, it's not like classic tex when there were only 256.

Comment: My anxiety was that each box might contain a large bit of detritus (a very large tikz or other image) as well as using an allocation slot. But perhaps the former is not a problem (mindset is that of someone bred in 1980 with an expensive 10Mb external drive).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A box defined defined with `\newsavebox` is basically nothing else than a wrapper command name for the corresponding box register. Checking for the macro name would do, e.g. with `\@ifundefined`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{mybox}{%
  \newsavebox{\mybox}%
}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX kernel provides a similar approach when working with regular macros through `\providecommand{<cs>}`. If `<cs>` already exists, nothing happens<sup>*</sup>, otherwise, `\providecommand` acts just like `\newcommand`. One can copy this approach to create `\providesavebox`:

> abc
>   def

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\providesavebox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \escapechar\m@ne\xdef\@gtempa{{\string#1}}%
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\@ifundefined\@gtempa
    {\newsavebox#1}%
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\providesavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{abc}
\usebox{\mybox}

\providesavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{def}
\usebox{\mybox}

\end{document}
```

Of course, alternatives to the above also exist, since boxes are referenced in the same way we reference macros. As such, you can also use some of the e-TeX conditionals provided in [How to conditionally define a new command in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2433/5764).

<sub><sup>*</sup>
Actually, the scratch macro `\@reserveda` is *redefined* instead of the provided macro name.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, the `stackengine` package provides a command `\savestack{<name>}{<box content>}` that places content in a saved box.  However, instead of using `\usebox` to recall it, one merely invokes the macro name to recall the box.

If one looks under the hood, the invocation `\savestack{\mybox}{<content>}` actually places `<content>` into a box named `\myboxcontent`.  And the macro `\mybox` is merely set to `\usebox{\myboxcontent}` as shown in the MWE.  Internally, it uses `\@ifundefined` to determine if it needs to create the box or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\mybox}{A}
\mybox\par
\savestack{\mybox}{B}
\mybox{} is the same as \usebox{\myboxcontent}
\end{document}
```

[image]