# \newcommand\whatever that ignores further \newcommand\whatever

Tags: macros

Is it possible to define a command `\foo` such that further `\newcommand\foo` (I do not mean `\renewcommand`) are ignored and do not return errors?

For example:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} % to be ignored!

\foo{This should print in red.}
```

The reason why I am asking for this is that I have a document `doc.tex` of the form

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\foo{Some text}
```

that I want to include in another document using `\input{doc.tex}`, and I'd like *Some text* to print in red (of course, in reality my problem is not about text color...).

Comment: If the goal is to avoid redefinitions in the **preamble**, you can likely define it initially (in the preamble) with `\AtBeginDocument{\let\foo\relax\newcommand\foo[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}`

Comment: What about `\providecommand\foo`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unless I misunderstand your point, that would still throw an error with a subsequent blue `\foo`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I thought of `\newcommand\foo` and then `\providecommand\foo` (as second usage)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I see.  I guess it will depend of whether the OP controls the subsequent definitions or not (I see mention of importing code from another file)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK, changing the second `\newcommand` to `providecommand` was transparent, so it works fine for me, thank you! Feel free to write an answer, I will also wait a bit to see if there are other more general solutions that avoid touching to the second `\newcommand`.

Comment: @anderstood: Well, it is not really a solution. If you have `\newcommand\foo` and `\providecommand\foo`, you already know that you're trying to define `\foo` again, unless you glue a bunch of files together and don't know in which file `\foo` is defined

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to conditionally define a new command in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2433/5764)

Comment: Related: [What do `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, and `\providecommand` do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change both `\newcommand` macros usages to `\providecommand`. The `\providecommand` will define a new macro only if there is no macro of the same name already, otherwise it will silently ignore the 2nd definition (or rather the trial to define it again) and do nothing at all.

Of course, it is still important which `\providecommand\foo` comes first. Depending on the real use case, loading as early as possible should be safe -- unless some really 'weird' usage such as interfering with the cross-reference/counter system or `ToC` - related issues is applied.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\providecommand\foo[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\providecommand\foo[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} % Will be ignored!


\begin{document}

\foo{This text should be printed in red -- and it is red}


\end{document}
```

[image]